# SharePoint 2010 - Get infopath complexity

Tags: infopath

Is there any way to assess the infopath complexity through powershell or any other method without opening the form?

The assessment is required to mark the form as high / medium / low complexity for migrating to SP Online.

Answer (score 0):

Document saved from InfoPath form is like a XML file only, so you can edit this XML document using PowerShell very easily.

**Sources**:

1. [Using powershell to read/modify/rewrite sharepoint xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905396/using-powershell-to-read-modify-rewrite-sharepoint-xml-document)
2. [Powershell to replace text in infopath XML files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/3afce6f0-a4b8-415b-91c4-97a2644d8d09/powershell-to-replace-text-in-infopath-xml-files?)
3. [Update xml in Infopath using powershell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d21701be-20ad-43c3-a003-8e51a08fb868/update-xml-in-infopath-using-powershell).